# Open window on UI Thread within try catch

Tags: c#, .net, avalonia

I have a method shown below that gets called after user clicks on a button. It does work, if something goes wrong `try catch` successfully catches the exception, but if window is opened on different thread than the UI, it throws exception after `catch` and application crashes. Solution seems simple - force window to open on UI thread. But compiler says that it isn't possible:

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda
> expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async'
> modifier.

And I have no idea how to bypass it.

I can remove await and it will work (exception caught, window opened), but it's not good practice to not await it.

```cs
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        DoTheThing();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            var messageBoxStandardWindow = MessageBox.Avalonia.MessageBoxManager
            .GetMessageBoxStandardWindow("Exception", e.Message);
            messageBoxStandardWindow.Show();
            Reset();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: "it's not good practice to not await it" - why?

Comment: Besides that is is unclear what `Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync` actually is, just call Invoke - which is not awaitable. Or just do not await InvokeAsync. It is not necessary.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy `This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.`

Comment: @Clemens Dispatcher.UIThread does not contain Invoke, only InvokeAsync

Comment: This is not WPF, right? As said, just don't await InvokeAsync. Or mark the lambda as async, that simple.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typical error that occurs when awaiting a non-asynchronous method (which doesn't return `Task`). Using `Task.Run` will automatically convert your expression's result to `Task`:

```cs
await Task.Run(() =>
{
  Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() =>
  {
    var messageBoxStandardWindow = MessageBox.Avalonia.MessageBoxManager
    .GetMessageBoxStandardWindow("Exception", e.Message);
       
    messageBoxStandardWindow.Show();
    Reset();
  })
});
```